# Ant design Select Options not vanish on scroll, It scrolls to other places upon scroll

Tags: select, antd

I am using ant design select in antd Drawer, Upon open select options if I scroll down the select options are still showing in down page .
Thank You.

Comment: kindly see the image for better understating of question.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZVKZ.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I had the same problem, I used this method and it worked for me.
**getPopupContainer**

```
 <CBSelectWrapper>
  <div id='select'>
   <label>{label}</label>
    <Select
     mode="tags"
     style={{ width: '100%' }}
     onChange={handleChange}
     tokenSeparators={[',']}
     getPopupContainer={() => document.getElementById('select')}
    >
     <Option key={value.id}>{value.title}</Option>
    </Select>
  </div>
 </CBSelectWrapper>
```

Answer (score 2):

One more solution:

```
<Select getPopupContainer={trigger => trigger.parentElement}>
```

In [documentation](https://ant.design/docs/react/faq#:%7E:text=issue%3A%20%233487%20%233438-,How%20do%20I%20prevent%20Select%20Dropdown%20DatePicker%20TimePicker%20Popover%20Popconfirm%20scrolling%20with%20the%20page%3F,-%23)